# Web-scraping in node.js in order to get all the CSS properties which are applied to each element of a web page

Tags: css, node.js, web-scraping

I would like to find a web-scraping technique based on node.js in order to get all the CSS properties which are applied to each element of a web page as the firebug does.

I tried to use jsdom by using the getMatchedCSSRules() but it seems that it doesn't work correctly. I think that's happening because the HTML content which I get by doing a GET request to a URL (i.e https://stackoverflow.com), it doesn't get rendered as it does in a web browser.

Does anybody know a way to do this in the node.js back-end part of an application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 100% emulating browser, you can't use a plain Node.js solution. You need use [WebDriver](http://webdriver.io) + Node.js.

With WebDriver you have [getCssProperty](http://webdriver.io/api/property/getCssProperty.html) method.

Does this solution work for you?

Comment: It seems that WebDriver is for testing purposes. My purpose of doing that is not related with testing. Can I use it anyway?

Comment: Exactly! You can

Comment: I tried it and it seems a possible solution. However, each time that I do a URL request and processing the content by using the web driver, it opens the firefox web browser which it seems that can't be avoided. I will try to use phantom.js which is a headless web browser emulator.

Comment: So yes, I can do this for sure by using either the WebDriver or the Phantom.js. However, I choose the second one because it consists of a headless web browser (it doesn't open the web browser) which covers my needs. Thanks galkin!